# create a matrix containing average of multiple matrices in R

Tags: r

I have multiple matrices with same dimensions as below:-

```
> A
     x y z
[1,] 2 4 3
[2,] 1 5 7
> B
     x y z
[1,] 4 3 3
[2,] 1 8 7
> C
     x y z
[1,] 4 3 3
[2,] 1 8 7
>
```

How do I create a new matrix of same dimension containing average of all the three matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `reduce` can be as:

```
library(purr)
ll <- list(A,B,C)
reduce(ll,`+`) / length(ll)

#          [,1]     [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 3.333333 3.333333    3
# [2,] 1.000000 7.000000    7
```

Comment: Error in reduce(ll, `+`) : could not find function "reduce"

Comment: I have included `library(purr)`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

minor change to MKR

```
tmp = Reduce('+', ll)/length(ll)
```

Comment: This is even better as you don't need any packages.